# Create a view with a select statement and a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I've created a view with a select statement, but I need to add a new field, USER_ID that shows the sequence (USER_ID_SEQ) incrementing with each record. Is it possible? I know that you can use UNION to create a view with two select statements, but I'm not sure on how to add a sequence to a view.
Below is the query I used for the first SELECT statement.

```
create or replace view FINAL_WEB_LOG
as
SELECT SESSION_DT, 
     C_IP, 
     CS_USER_AGENT,
     tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(web_link) AS t_varchar2_tab)) WEBLINKS
FROM web_views_tab    
GROUP BY C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT, SESSION_DT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a nested query in `select` as:

```
  create or replace view FINAL_WEB_LOG
  as
  SELECT (SELECT USER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL from dual) as USER_ID,
     SESSION_DT, 
     C_IP, 
     CS_USER_AGENT,
     tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(web_link) AS t_varchar2_tab)) WEBLINKS
 FROM web_views_tab    
 GROUP BY C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT, SESSION_DT
```

This should work but I believe `USER_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL` will keep increasing in each refresh of the view.

If you just want to have a ID field associated then simply use `ROWNUM` as:

```
  create or replace view FINAL_WEB_LOG
  as
  SELECT ROWNUM as USER_ID,
     SESSION_DT, 
     C_IP, 
     CS_USER_AGENT,
     tab_to_string(CAST(COLLECT(web_link) AS t_varchar2_tab)) WEBLINKS
 FROM web_views_tab    
 GROUP BY C_IP, CS_USER_AGENT, SESSION_DT
```

Comment: SQL Server has a ROWCOUNT() function - I assume oracle has something similar. Would that be of use to you?

Comment: Thanks, but apparently sequence number is inappropriate in this kind of statement. It would be much easier to do it with a table instead, but the COLLECT function works properly when it comes to a VIEW.

Comment: @DaleM Do you mean `ROWNUM`?

Comment: Dale M - I'm not sure if that works with a VIEW but I'll look into it! Thank you.

Comment: @user1874311 You want to use `SEQUENCE` hance replied that way. I would advice you to use `ROWNUM` instead.

Comment: @YogendraSingh - maybe. I have never worked with oracle so I have no idea. Seems to be the same sort of thing though.

Comment: If you want more control on the "order" of the generated "sequence" number, `row_number()` might be a better choice.